# Select case conditional logic

Tags: cognito-forms

I have a quiz that I have created with Cognito Forms.  I want to be able to display one of four different answers to the user when he/she finishes the quiz.  I have two conditional fields that sum up the value of the answers resulting in either a value above 0 or below.  I need another conditional logic field to determine if the other two fields are above 0 or below zero.

So,

- Case 1: Condition1 > 0 && Condition2 > 0;
- Case 2:Condition1 < 0 && Condition2 > 0;

and so on and so forth.

- How do I code a conditional field statement that evaluates the value of the other two conditional field values?
- And do I need to set them to text or number since the value in the two conditional field statements are numbers?

I'm used to select/case statements in VBA, but haven't got my head wrapped around Cognito's logic yet.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a developer with Cognito Forms.

You should be able to set up a Calculation field, that checks the two conditional fields. The best way to go about doing this would be to set up the conditional fields to a type of number. You can then check them to see if they are > 0 or if they are < and > 0.

Building the calculation for this without knowing what you want to display or what the field names are can be a bit tricky, but you should be able to use something close to the following.

```
=if (Condition1 > 0 and Condition2 > 0) then 1 else if (Condition1 < 0 and Condition2 > 0) then 2 else 0
```

You can continue with this for as many if/else statements as you need.